# How to make the expand/collapse animation in Tree smooth similar to the effect in Toolbar.addSearchCommand()?

Tags: codenameone

The default animation when expanding (or collapsing) a sub-tree in the CN1 `Tree` is not smooth: the expanded elements kind of drop in and the list kind of jumps back when collapsing. Whereas the animation used for the `Toolbar.addSearchCommand()` is smooth and agreeable to watch (the hidden/shown elements all expand/collapse at the same time in a really elegant way).

I tried to find a way to get make the Tree animation smooth, but haven't figured it out. Any suggestions for how it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit more challenging for tree than the search command. The search command just moves things within a fixed area. The tree needs to both expand the area and bring in hidden elements while pushing the rest of the stuff down. Since the drawn area is larger the container into which the node expands needs to grow and the animation doesn't grow it fast enough.

Anyway, I'm not sure that it can be made smoother in the current design of tree. It's possible you can create a custom tree component and use a more controlled type of animation like `replace` or multiple stages of animation e.g. expand/collapse, animate in/out.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried and it works for expansion (I add the expanded sub-elements and use getParent.animateLayout()). This makes the added elements expand smoothly. However, when I remove the subelements and use getParent.animateLayout(), it makes all the sub-elements instantly disappear and then whatever was below smoothly moves up. So overall better, but not symmetric. I also tried to use setHidden(true) on the collapsed elements first - like Search does - but the animation result is the same as just described. Which is strange since it works in Search. Any suggestion for what I need to do?

Comment: When removing do 2 stages too. Move the X / Y position of the animated elements to a position outside the area and use animateUnlayout. Then use animateLayout to fix the resulting invalid layout